# framer-motion ios 9 compatibility

Tags: reactjs, ios9, framer-motion

`framer-motion` uses Proxy, but after importing `proxy-polyfill`, `motion.div` exported from 'framer-motion' is still undefined.

How can I make it work with ios 9?

```js
import 'proxy-polyfill';
import 'core-js/stable';
import 'regenerator-runtime/runtime';

import { motion } from 'framer-motion';
console.log(motion.div) // undefined
```

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: @xaphod https://github.com/framer/motion/issues/674

Comment: Thanks. I just went back to v1.x and it worked for me